# How to handle dimensions/sizes with wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: html, css, wkhtmltopdf, dimension

I'm using wkhtmltopdf to convert some HTML to PDF. Is there a proper way to handle sizes and dimensions?

I mean - how can I style an image with the dimension of 100px x 1oopx that it is printed in the following dimension 10mm x 10mm (I'm using DINA4: 210mm x 297mm)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use a variety of units in the print styles, including cm and mm. So something like this should work:

```
@media print {
  img.selector { width:1cm; height:1cm; }
}
```

Or perhaps just:

```
@media print {
  img[width="100"]{ width:1cm; height:1cm; }
}
```